# Label extremes of HTML5 range input

Tags: html, user-interface, range

I'd like to label the extremes of a range input for ordinal data (0-10) to unambiguate the UI. [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) suggests that I should be able to use a `datalist` within my form like this:

```html
<datalist id="ord">
  <option value="0" label="Identical"></option>
  <option value="10" label="Very different"></option>
</datalist>
...
<input type="range" list="ord" min="0" max="10" value="5" name="name"/>
```

The documentation then warns that:

> Currently, no browser fully supports these features. Firefox doesn't support hash marks and labels at all, for example, while Chrome supports hash marks but doesn't support labels. Version 66 (66.0.3359.181) of Chrome supports labels but the  tag has to be styled with CSS as its display property is set to none by default, hiding the labels.

My testing confirms this --- in Chromium (Brave), QtWebEngine (Qutebrowser), and Firefox, either nothing was displayed or tickmarks were displayed without lables. Is there a standard and minimal way to add labels to a range slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add separate elements, probably [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements, on either side of your input, then use CSS to position them appropriately.

As far as tick-marks are concerned, there isn't a standard way to add those. However, with the concept of [progressive enhancement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Progressive_Enhancement) in mind, feel free to add the `<datalist>` without the `label` attributes (since you'll have those set using the above-referenced elements) so that users who access your site on browsers that *do* support the tick marks *can* see them.